# Unity websockets latency is higher on native mobile app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, websocket, socket.io

Im using this package which implements websockets
In the unity editor ( On android in player settings ) Ping is 70-80
On my galaxy s23 phone , the ping is 150-200. The laptop uses the same wifi as the phone.
On the same galaxy phone, in webgl in the browser , 70-80 ping. So clearly the issue is in the android app.
Any solutions to this? server is nodejs + socket.io

Expecting the same ping as in the browser webgl version, and the editor version

Reproduced also on IOS